# Center div in function of another element

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-5

I have a nav bar with two image.

I search to center navbarCollapse div like if there is no image...
Actually it centers in relation to image

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-white navbar-light sticky-top px-4 px-lg-5">
  <a href="index.html" class="navbar-brand d-flex align-items-center">
    <img class="img-fluid me-1" style="max-height:80px" src="https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/uor1HwGTyEGY.jpg" alt="">
    <img class="img-fluid me-1" style="max-height:80px" src="https://gcdnb.pbrd.co/images/2z5kQm8hWV3t.jpg" alt="">
  </a>
  <div id="navbarCollapse" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
    <div class="navbar-nav mx-auto bg-light pe-4 py-3 py-lg-0">
      <a href="index.html" class="nav-item nav-link active">Welcome</a>
      <a href="about.html" class="nav-item nav-link">About</a>
      <a href="residential.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Residential</a>
      <a href="commercial.html" class="nav-item nav-link">commercial</a>
      <a href="quote.html" class="nav-item nav-link ">Quote</a>
      <a href="contact.html" class="nav-item nav-link">Contact</a>
    </div>
    <div class="h-100 d-lg-inline-flex align-items-center d-none">
      <a class="btn btn-square rounded-circle bg-light text-primary me-2" href="https://www.facebook.com/xxx"><i class="fab fa-facebook-f"></i></a>

    </div>
  </div>
</nav>
```

you can see an example who are more usefull then snippet here
https://jsfiddle.net/n0435ok6/

Comment: Could you please edit the Snippet I've made from your posted HTML to include the relevant Bootstrap?

Comment: i posted a link who show the issue

Comment: Also provide any refer that how you want it look like.